# How can I secure a Javascript call to a Java Servlet via XMLHttpRequest such that it cannot be used if the url is manually entered into a browser?

Tags: java, javascript, security, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I currently have a webpage that uses a javascript that does the following:

```
function callSomething(parm) {
    req = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            req = false;
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (req) {
        var url_str = "/Servlet?parm=" + parm;
        req.open("GET", url_str, false);
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.send(null);
        // process the response
    }
    return something;
}
```

My concern is that if someone enters the full URL manually (e.g. "http://somesampleserver.com/Servlet?parm=something") in an browser window, the response is also displayed. How do I prevent that from happening? I only want the code to be able to get the response.

Comment: BTW why do you want to limit this?  Maybe if you sort out your architecture then you will not need to artificially limit the browser.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Many obvious reasons. Main one being scrapers that just iterate over parm and grab all data on the site without loading any pages

Comment: It is not trivial to protect an http request. You may need to have people log in (probably the better solution but may not be practical), examine referrer (can be faked or be suppressed, both a pain) and so on

Comment: thanks mplungjan. but if I simply want the request to be unavailable to anyone who manually plugs in the url and parameters through the browser, would Ravi's suggestion of using POST suffice?

Comment: @mplungjan I realise that in the real world scrapers can be a problem, do the OP specifically mentioned `someone enters the full URL manually` - hence I was wondering what his/her real motive is.

Comment: Right - yes a post would be sufficient. I would need a plugin like Postman or curl to simulate a post. I could also write a bookmarklet to post from your page

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check if this was an XHR request. You can check the [X-Requested-With](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) header

```
Boolean isXHR = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
```

More on that [here](http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2009/07/detect-ajax-request.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems session framework can help. Like [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) & [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).
With those frameworks, only valid session connection can visit resources(URL). Otherwise, it will redirect to login page(customized) automatically.